# Play a sound triggered from emitting a particle

Tags: particles, audio

I have a spaceship and it has a particle system for firing lasers. I am wondering if there is a way to play a sound when it emits a particle.

I have tried grouping the particle with the speaker and emitting the whole group but that doesn't work. I don't know if it should or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3D animation the sound and video are generally two separate things. Supposing you did get your sound to play with the particle system, you would still need to out put the whole animation to a video format including sound. Which rules out a image sequence, the best way to render an animation.

It will be easier to just render out your animation of the ship firing its lasers. Then in something like the [video sequence editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage) (or any other video editor) just add the sound file at the right time to match the firing lasers.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you'd want to do in the game engine. You could probably place a speaker near (right in front of/next to) your "guns" that is triggered when a particle comes within a certain range.